# Flyway produces MySQL syntax error while raw script does not

Tags: mysql, flyway

For the following MySql script Flyway produces a MySQL syntax error while running the script directly in something like Navicat works fine. Can anyone tell me why that is?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RegressionTest_Genealogy (OUT Success TINYINT)
BEGIN  
    DECLARE MetricVerification TINYINT;
    SET Success = 0;

    SELECT COUNT(MERTRICID) INTO MetricVerification FROM metrics_temp WHERE lft = 0 OR rgt = 0;

    IF MetricVerification = 0 THEN
        SET Success = 1;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Don't forget to share your error.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to issue a delimiter change first to make this work, as per default the delimiter is ; which is contained in your procedure body.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE RegressionTest_Genealogy (OUT Success TINYINT)
BEGIN  
DECLARE MetricVerification TINYINT;

SET Success = 0;

SELECT COUNT(MERTRICID) INTO MetricVerification FROM metrics_temp WHERE lft = 0 OR rgt = 0;

IF MetricVerification = 0 THEN
    SET Success = 1;
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```